# Mongodb benchRun crashed when parallel connections are more than 128

Tags: mongodb, benchmarking

While doing performance measurement in mongodb using [this](https://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/reference/js-benchmarking-harness/#js-benchmarking-harness) test with benchRun(). benchRun crashed when x was greater that 128.

Following is the stacktrace:

```
for ( var x = 1; x <= 256; x *= 2) {     res = benchRun( {         parallel : x ,         seconds : 5 ,         ops : ops     } );     print( "threads: " + x + "\t queries/sec: " + res.query ); }
threads: 1   queries/sec: 9710.149419988862
threads: 2   queries/sec: 20123.612706850294
threads: 4   queries/sec: 20104.887937887142
threads: 8   queries/sec: 20021.93510847081
threads: 16  queries/sec: 20047.279206425876
threads: 32  queries/sec: 22452.635848061327
threads: 64  queries/sec: 22909.73264053509
threads: 128     queries/sec: 22919.056958070505
2015-08-04T11:48:21.733+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.735+0000 I CONTROL  
 0x80c9e9 0x7c1871 0x7a8902 0x77fc83 0x7808fd 0x858c54 0x7fd9c1794182 0x7fd9c089547d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"40C9E9"},{"b":"400000","o":"3C1871"},{"b":"400000","o":"3A8902"},{"b":"400000","o":"37FC83"},{"b":"400000","o":"3808FD"},{"b":"400000","o":"458C54"},{"b":"7FD9C178C000","o":"8182"},{"b":"7FD9C079B000","o":"FA47D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.4", "gitVersion" : "nogitversion", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.13.0-46-generic", "version" : "#77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "281BC2D7C110F599E334B1B8DCCFA7ED04F4DD89" }, { "b" : "7FFF61E5B000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "88E7559031E488BC215236F4181BD1FAF9A458F0" }, { "b" : "7FD9C178C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9318E8AF0BFBE444731BB0461202EF57F7C39542" }, { "b" : "7FD9C1584000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92FCF41EFE012D6186E31A59AD05BDBB487769AB" }, { "b" : "7FD9C1380000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C1AE4CB7195D337A77A3C689051DABAA3980CA0C" }, { "b" : "7FD9C107C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "19EFDDAB11B3BF5C71570078C59F91CF6592CE9E" }, { "b" : "7FD9C0D76000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D76B71E905CB867B27CEF230FCB20F01A3178F5" }, { "b" : "7FD9C0B60000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D0AA71411580EE6C08809695C3984769F25725B" }, { "b" : "7FD9C079B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "30C94DC66A1FE95180C3D68D2B89E576D5AE213C" }, { "b" : "7FD9C19AA000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9F00581AB3C73E3AEA35995A0C50D24D59A01D47" } ] }}
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0x80c9e9]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0x7c1871]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j+0xB2) [0x7a8902]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo14BenchRunWorker24generateLoadOnConnectionEPNS_12DBClientBaseE+0x5EF3) [0x77fc83]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo14BenchRunWorker3runEv+0xED) [0x7808fd]
 mongo(+0x458C54) [0x858c54]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7fd9c1794182]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fd9c089547d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-08-04T11:48:21.737+0000 I -        

***aborting after invariant() failure

2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
2015-08-04T11:48:21.736+0000 I -        Invariant failure bsonTemplateEvaluator.setId(_id) == BsonTemplateEvaluator::StatusSuccess src/mongo/shell/bench.cpp 349
```

Nothing unsual was found in logs except the connection end message from client. Total number of connections was about 150. What cab be the possible reasons of this issue?

Mongodb version:2.6.7, 3.0.4